# How to handle more than one tags in SOAP request Body

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

I am using SOAP Webservice in my App. The problem I am facing is,there is one extra tag in SOAP request body. Because of that I am getting SOAP Fault error "SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@40516ce8".

Here is the SOAP request....

```
POST /appws.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xxxxxx.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://xxxxxxx.com/saveCustomerProfile"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<saveCustomerProfile xmlns="http://xxxxxx.com/">
  <customerProfile>
    <id>long</id>
    <name>string</name>
    <lastName>string</lastName>
    <phoneNumber>string</phoneNumber>
    <zipCode>string</zipCode>
    <email>string</email>
    <birthday>string</birthday>
    <gender>string</gender>
    <emailExclusiveSavings>boolean</emailExclusiveSavings>
    <textExclusiveSavings>boolean</textExclusiveSavings>
  </customerProfile>
</saveCustomerProfile>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is the code I am using to call this webservice

```
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "saveCustomerProfile");
    request.addProperty("id", 0);
            request.addProperty("name","aaaaa");
            request.addProperty("lastName","bbbbbb");
            request.addProperty("phoneNumber", "1234567890");
            request.addProperty("zipCode", "1234");
            request.addProperty("email", "123@gmail.com");
            request.addProperty("birthday", "02/02/2011");
            request.addProperty("gender", "male");


      request.addProperty("emailExclusiveSavings","true");
  request.addProperty("textExclusiveSavings", "false");

      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            System.out.println("response "+envelope.getResponse());
```

I found where the problem is happening.

```
  <saveCustomerProfile xmlns="http://xxxxxx.com/">
     <customerProfile>
```

Normally only one main tag will be there inside SOAP body, here I have two and  . I do not know how to handle it. I have checked with some other SOAP Webservices all are working on the same code. Please help  me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [***Tutorial***](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)..Might help you:

Comment: Thanks for your reply....But this is not helpful, that is how we can make SOAP request normal way, not like what I am looking for.